# Review Board Python Web API

Tags: python, api, review-board

I'm new with using third-party APIs, and I was trying to get the Review Board Web API to work in python.

However, I was confused about 3 things:

```
from rbtools.api.client import RBClient

client = RBClient('http://localhost:8080/')
root = client.get_root()
```

My first question: is `http://localhost:8080/` the server that is running the ReviewBoard server? Is there some sort of test server that I can use instead of running my own?

Again, I don't have much experience with APIs so I was wondering if I needed to do some form of authentication before making these calls.

Finally, if I must set up my own Review Board server to try out the API. Would it be possible to get some code for a very simple example as to how to make the simplest POST and GET request you can think of with minimal setup if for example my server was running on `http://localhost:8080/`?

```
Reference : http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/0.5/api/overview/
```

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean by your last question.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) I was looking for a set of commands that would perform a simple GET request (POST if possible too) that I could use to model all my later requests on once I have a server running on my local machine

Comment: The Web API docs will then definitely tell you want the GET/POST requests should look like. If you're going to be making them yourself, I'd like to suggest you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org). I'm a maintainer of the project and would be happy to help you with any questions you have. There's also a tag for it here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: the answer seems to be yes although their docs don't make it entirely clear.

Their docs say:

```
Here is an example of how to instantiate the client, and retrieve the Root List Resource resource:
```

Before the code snippet your pasted. That makes me think that the url being passed is whatever you're trying to use, e.g., you could have that set up on a networked machine called monty_python running on port 5050, then you would do:

```
client = RBClient('http://monty_python:5050/')
```

As for a test server you should check the documentation they have about their [Web API](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/webapi/).

Their examples don't seem to show any authentication being performed in the overview. If you check in other sections (e.g., [Tutorial: Creating a Pull Request](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/0.5/api/tutorial/#creating-a-review-request)) you'll see them demonstrate how to authenticate and what can be done after authenticating.

As for your last question, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but you should probably check the docs I found for their [Web API](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/webapi/)